# A Five Letter Word

Tags: riddle, word

I can:

> Be a letter - but only one
>
> Be furniture - but only one
>
> Be a place in a fruit - but only one
>
> Be from the UK - but only one
>
> Be after all the positive numbers - Except one

I am a five letter word. **Who am I?**

Hint/Clue:

> It has six anagrams believe it or not

Hint/Clue (Last one)

> The letter is also a roman numeral

Comment: For he furniture part. Does it necessarily *have* to be furniture?

Comment: Yes it is a furniture item connected to the word

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is my egregious suggestion

> **times**

Be a letter - but only one

> x - is often used for the times symbol, and is the only letter it stands for.

Be furniture - but only one

> times table - for multiplying , and it's the only furniture commonly written alongside times.

Be a place in a fruit - but only one

> Times Square - a place (Square) in "The Big Apple" (fruit) with "The" making this only one.

Be from the UK - but only one

> The Times - a famous newspaper from the UK, with "The" meaning only one.

Be after all the positive numbers - Except one

> times - can follow two, three, etc. We do say one times any number - so only works if it means events.

Comment: According to [qat](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=%2Ftimes&ent=Search&dict=0) this also satisfies Hint 1: rot13(rzvgf vgrzf zrgvf zvgrf fzvgr fgvzr) - I think you've cracked it!

Comment: Nice :) I was actually thinking of the exact same word, but didn't make those connections.  I was thinking about rot13(*nantenzf* bs gvzrf naq tbg "vgrzf" nf gur pybfrfg guvat gb sheavgher, urapr zl pbzzrag nobir. Ohg aba bs gur bgure guerr yvarf znqr frafr.)

Comment: And there it is. Happy to see this got solved!